# Two functions being equivalent if integrals equal

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Assume two bounded integral functions $f, g:A \to R$ for the bounded set A:
if $f(x)\le g(x)$, and $\int_A f=\int_A g$, then f and g agree except on a set of measure 0.

I know how to prove if f and g agree except on a set of measure zero, then $\int_A f=\int_A g$. But I am trying to prove the other direction, it is obvious if f=g for all x, but why would f

Comment: Can you prove that if $h \geq 0$ and $\int_A h = 0$ then $h=0$ a.s.?

Comment: What is the integral of $g-f$?

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed in two steps:

1. Show that if $h\geq0$ and $\int_A h = 0$ then $h=0$ a.s.
2. Reduce the general case of $f,g: A \to R$ to the case in 1. by considering $h := g-f$.

We show step 1. by contradiction. Assume there exists a $B \subseteq A$ such that $B$ has a positive measure and for all $x \in B$ it holds that $h(x)>0$. Then we yield
\begin{align}\label{ineq}\tag{1}
\int_A h \geq \int_B h > 0,
\end{align}
where the first inequality follows by $h \geq 0$ and $B \subseteq A$. This is in contradiction to the assumption $\int_A h = 0$.

Comment: thank you so much, so for step 2, we reduce the case f<=g to h=g-f=0 or g=f?

Comment: You are welcome :) For the case $f \leq g$ we consider $h := g - f \geq 0$. Since $\int_A f = \int_A g$ is equivalent to $\int_A h = 0$ by the linearity of integrals, we have $h=0$ a.s. by step 1. But $h=0$ a.s. is equivalent to $f=g$ a.s. by definition of $h$ which completes the proof.

Comment: Got it, thank you:) last question: what is the definition of f and g agreeing? is it just f=g and integrals equal? I am trying to relate how proving f<g on a set of measure 0 to the final step of proof on this question

Comment: for a measure $\mu$ we say "$f = g$ $\mu$-a.s." if and only if  $\mu(B) = 0$ with $ B := \{ x \in A | f(x) \neq g(x) \}$. Does it help?